# API get request being run after component loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an issue where i am trying to pass my api data to another component. This works perfectly when the app runs initially, but after i click the refresh button the object where i store my data is initially undefined because the data isnt being passed.

I made a temporary solution where i check that the data being passed to the component isnt undefined, but i'm sure there is a better work around to this issue.

The following is my App component:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        const getData = async () => {
            const res = fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((result) => setData(result))
                .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
            setLoading(false);
        };

        getData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <Header />
                    <div className="content">
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/about">
                                <About />
                            </Route>
                            <Route path="/">
                                {data !== undefined ? (
                                    <MainSection
                                        covidData={data}
                                        load={loading}
                                    />
                                ) : null}
                            </Route>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

And the following is my main section where i pass the data and aim to use it within this component.

```
function MainSection({ covidData, load }) {
    console.log(covidData);
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <div className="main-section">
                <div className="main-left">
                    <div className="alert-btn">
                        <img src={covidAlert} alt="info" />
                    </div>
```

Refreshing the page leads to the error: cannot read property of 'coviddata' undefined

Comment: Any "better approach" is really up to you and how you want the application to behave.  What you're currently doing is correct, you can't *use* the data until you *have* the data.  Currently you're simply not showing the component until the data is available.  What do you want to do instead?  Show a loading spinner?  Something else?

Comment: As an aside, your `loading` value appears to be misdirecting you.  You currently call `setLoading(false)` before the loading completes.